# Create a single character varaible from a list with several characters

Tags: r, list

I have a data frame that includes one list

```
df <- data.frame(names=1:6)
df$V1<- list(c("NO"), c("NO","NO"), c("NO", "YES"), c("YES", "NO", "YES"), c("NO", "NO", "NO"), c("YES"))

  names           V1
1     1           NO
2     2       NO, NO
3     3      NO, YES
4     4 YES, NO, YES
5     5   NO, NO, NO
6     6          YES
```

I would like to create a third variable that gives me a "YES" whenever a list contains any "YES" and a "NO" if the list contains only "NO", like this:

```
  names           V1  V2
1     1           NO  NO
2     2       NO, NO  NO
3     3      NO, YES YES
4     4 YES, NO, YES YES
5     5   NO, NO, NO  NO
6     6          YES YES
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: I believe it is "R".

Comment: Sorry, I´m new at this. It is R

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. What is the rule to create this new third variable?

Comment: what is your rule? any "yes?" `df$V2 <- c('NO', 'YES')[grepl('YES', df$V1) + 1]`

Comment: My rule is: if any within a list is "YES", this works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `ifelse`. If there is any case of "YES", then V2 = YES, else V2 = NO.

```
df$V2 <- ifelse(grepl("YES", df$V1), "YES", "NO")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a sapply or lapply over the V1 variable to do whatever you want to it. If, for example, you want the last element:

```
df$V2 = sapply(df$V1, tail, n = 1)

> df
  names           V1  V2
1     1           NO  NO
2     2       NO, NO  NO
3     3      NO, YES YES
4     4 YES, NO, YES YES
5     5   NO, NO, NO  NO
6     6          YES YES
```

This runs the tail function over every element in df$V1, one by one.

Comment: Thank you, Luis. I want to get a YES for all those that have a "YES" regardless the position, and I'm not sure what function does this in a list.

Comment: In that case, you need a function that takes in a vector of characters then spits out a YES if there is at least one YES. You can do that with df$V2 = sapply(df$V1, function(x){any(x == "YES")})